# AVR:LDI instruction

Tags: avr, avr-gcc

In 8bit-avr instruction set, instruction LDI is defined as LDI Rd,K;

For example LDI R16,$10; and it takes 1 cycles to complete.

In the same document i read that we can change register Rd specific bit like this:

LDI R16,(1<<7); So how many cycles is required to perform this instruction?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The expression like (1<<7) is actually constant, because its value is computed in compile time. It is equal to `ldi R16, 128`. As long this is the same instruction, the execution time will be the same.